Why isn't Google Chrome showing basic auth?
Chrome no longer shows the popup to enter the details for HTTP or HTTPS basic auth and so it returns a 401 error. It used to, like my router's settings page, my own https site.
I have tried restarting; Chrome, the PC, router. Using incognito mode and Opera, Firefox shows the auth pop up.
Adding in the auth details "http://username:pass@website/" to the url works for FireFox but not Chrome/Opera.
Postman does work when the auth values are sent in the request.
not using any proxies.
How can I enter the name and password for basic auth in Chrome?

Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

I don't know why it doesn't work, but you can try putting the username and password as part of the URL. Like: http://username:password@example.com/

Firefox shows it but what about other browsers? You only mentioned them. Do you use any proxies in Chrome? Did you test with multiple websites?

adding in the 'username:pass@' didn't do anything for chrome, but does work for FireFox, even works as a bookmark, thats cool.
I have tried with Opera with the same result as chrome, cmiiw but they are both chromium like everything but firefox arn't they?
Postman does work when the auth values are sent in the request.
not using any proxies.
I only know of 2 sites that use the basic auth, my router and a website I'm working on.

According to ADMX.HELP, you need to set HKLM/Software/Policies/Google/Chrome/BasicAuthOverHTTPEnabled to DWORD:1
You may also have to set HKLM/Software/Policies/Google/Chrome/AuthSchemes to include basic, e.g., REG_SZ:'basic, digest, ntlm, negotiate'. If this policy is set, and does not include 'basic', setting the previous policy will be ignored.
